# How do I handle WebClient/Proxies C#

Tags: c#, error-handling, webclient

What is the best practice to handle my Webclient requests? 
Right now, as you can see, I just have it displaying the "failed" proxy and the error type to an error log.

I've looked around but have not been able to find much information on the proper way to handle.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
           {            
               foreach (var line in fileInfo)
           {               
                   foreach (var lines in proxies)
                   {                     
                       WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(lines);
                       try
                       {
                           client.Proxy = proxy;
                           string downloadString = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("url");

                       }

                       catch (WebException ex)
                       {
                           if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.RequestProhibitedByCachePolicy)
                           { 

                               errorTb.Text += lines + " ERROR request prohib";
                               client.Dispose();
                               continue;
                           }
```

In order to get my program running efficiently I would need to set some sort of timer for each proxy?

Thank you very much for your time, it is much appreciated.

Comment: To clarify on top of the title, I am meaning WebExceptions.